# How pillowfight works in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

While going through docs for pillowfight the “–num-threads” definition showing that each thread is assigned its own object. Is there any way we can see in CB UI or cli commands to verify how couchbase is behaving w.r.t "--num-threads" while performing pillowfight test on cb cluster.

We had given num-threads as 20. Are all 20 threads go and search one document or each thread will search different docs? Is there any way we can confirm how pillowfight works w.r.t "num-threads".

```
/opt/couchbase/bin/cbc-pillowfight -U couchbase://xx.xx.xx.xx/data1 -u -P --min-size 1000 --max-size 1000 --json --set-pct 0 --batch-size 1 --num-items 24000000 --num-threads 20 --rate-limit 8000 --key-prefix a --no-population;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pillowfight will spawn multiple threads that each operate according to the same command-line arguments...so yes, they will operate over the same set of documents.

What I often do is use a simple bash command to launch different pillowfight instances while varying the item prefix for each.